gRPC behind Istio Gateway
I'm having trouble debugging why my gRPC servers cannot be reached behind an Istio gateway. Here's how to reproduce:
# Use enough resources for Istio.
minikube start --memory=16384 --cpus=4
# Set up Istio in ambient mode.
istioctl install --set profile=ambient --skip-confirmation
# Set up Gateway API.
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/gateway-api/releases/download/v1.2.0/standard-install.yaml

Now, apply the following objects, using a pre-built example gRPC server that listens on port 50051:
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: foo-gateway
spec:
  gatewayClassName: istio
  listeners:
    - name: foo-grpc
      protocol: HTTP
      port: 50051
      allowedRoutes:
        kinds:
          - kind: GRPCRoute
---
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: GRPCRoute
metadata:
  name: foo-api-v1
spec:
  parentRefs:
    - name: foo-gateway
  rules:
    - backendRefs:
        - name: foo-api-v1
          port: 50051
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: foo-api-v1
  labels:
    app: foo-api-v1
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 50051
  selector:
    app: foo-api-v1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: foo-api-v1
  labels:
    account: foo-api-v1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: foo-api-v1
  labels:
    app: foo-api-v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: foo-api-v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: foo-api-v1
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: foo-api-v1
      # Use a stock example gRPC server.
      containers:
        - name: foo-api-v1
          image: 'docker.io/grpc/java-example-hostname'
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 50051

Once it's all up and running, we can invoke RPC's directly on foo-api-v1 service like so:
kubectl port-forward svc/foo-api-v1 8080:50051
grpcurl -plaintext -format text -d 'name: "Jimbo"' localhost:8080 helloworld.Greeter/SayHello
# message: "Hello Jimbo, from foo-api-v1-5678866d86-sp9wt"

It works, cool. However, I can't reach it through the gateway:
kubectl port-forward svc/foo-gateway-istio 9090:50051
grpcurl -plaintext -format text -d 'name: "Jimbo"' localhost:9090 helloworld.Greeter/SayHello
# Error invoking method "helloworld.Greeter/SayHello": failed to query for service descriptor "helloworld.Greeter": server does not support the reflection API

It's not just an issue with reflection. It still does not work even if you specify the service definition with grpcurl:
grpcurl -plaintext -format text -d 'name: "Jimbo"' -proto helloworld.proto localhost:9090 helloworld.Greeter/SayHello
# ERROR:
#   Code: Unavailable
#   Message: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: protocol error

I've tried inspecting the traffic with Kubeshark and found a gRPC request from foo-gateway-istio-77bc48898f-nrg9w/envoy to itself. It has the following POST data (text/plain):
{"field_1":"Jimbo"}

This is odd. It seems like Istio's gateway is doing automatic JSON transcoding and using a default field name ("field_1") instead of a proper field name. That would explain "protocol error" from upstream. But I'm not sure what to do about this.

Refer this github issue and Istio documentation which my helps to resolve your issue.
